# Google analytics event tracking on javascript form

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

How can I add this "_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’" code to tell google to track form submit event? This is not working right now!

I want to track only successful form subbmit events.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#LoadingLizings').show();
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            type:"POST",
            data: $("#lizings").serialize(),
            url:"assets/process_lizings.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function() {

                _gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘form’, ’submitted’, ’lizings_form’,, ’true’]);

                $('#lizings :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#lizings_form').fadeTo( "slow", 0.05, function() {
                    $('#LoadingLizings').hide();
                    $('#LizingsSuccess').fadeIn();
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#lizings_form').fadeTo( "slow", 0.05, function() {
                    $('#LoadingLizings').hide();
                    $('#LizingsError').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hey maarcs, are you sure that the JavaScript is working? Do you have a link to the actual webpage?

Comment: no, this code is not working! Im trying to find a working solution

Comment: Hey maarcs, the first thing I see is that submitHandler is not enclosed in any type of call. Can you give us more of your JavaScript and the HTML that you are trying to validate?

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the quotes for your code, assuming that is the exact code you have on your site. You're using smart quotes, which should be replaced by single quotes ('), like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'form', 'submitted', 'lizings_form']);
```

Also, by default, events are interactive, so you don't need the last "true" parameter.